# Import Text File in to MySQL Database error

Tags: mysql, text-files

I am writing a query to import a text file into one of my tables but it is giving me an error. The following is my query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\bobc\Desktop\inpuut.csv' INTO TABLE Car;
```

My error is:

"SQL Error (1045): Access denied for user 'bob_root'@'123.456.78.123' (using password: yes)"

I am currently using a mysql server on hostgator and I don't know if I need to change any settings on there to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Your user needs to have the `FILE` privilege. If the MySQL instance is administered by Host Gator, ask their support to give you the `FILE` privilege - they might say no due to security concerns, but worth a try. If you are running your own instance, log in as root to MySQL and issue:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO `user`@`host`
```

replacing `user` and `host` with the appropriate values.

Comment: Yea, it seems like no matter where I look, there is no solution for it except to contact host gator. My ultimate goal was to write a query for a python script which imports the data from a text file into a table. I ended up using python to read the text file instead and then inserted the data that way. Thanks for the help though!